# SVPullToRefresh not working with UICollectionView when content height is less than the height

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, pull-to-refresh, contentsize

I'm using [SVPullToRefresh](https://github.com/samvermette/SVPullToRefresh) to enable pull to refresh in `UICollectionView`. But I find a problem with it. Suppose my collection view size is 320(width) x 300(height) then if content size height of collection view less than the height than the pull to refresh view is not working. Means, when I am trying to drag down (pull down the collection view) it'll not drag the pull area and not even show pull to refresh view.

What can be a work around for this? I tried updating collection view's content size but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think setting

```
self.collectionView.alwaysBounceVertical = YES;
```

will do the trick.